# How to do two POST requests for visitors with JS disabled on one submit button?

Tags: php, html, http, post

I got help with solving a problem in this thead: [Redirect with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614076/redirect-with-post-data). Now that I decided that the whole site and even this function must work when JS is disabled I need to get some suggestions for a non JS solution as well.

The need is:

User fills in a form and click  on a button.

When clicked part of the form is saved in the db and part is posted to another server (payment-server). The user should only need to click once.

Comment: dont know exactly what you mean, please specify. why not use php script for it (with curl to the payment server?)

Comment: Don't payment servers provide callbacks that include details like addresses?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the browser to re-send the data of a HTTP Post request to another URI, the HTTP/1.1 protocol offers the [307 (temporary redirect) response status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8) to signal such to the HTTP-client (Browser):

```
header('HTTP/1.0 307 Temporary Redirect',$replace=true,307);
header('Location: some_new_url_here');
```

Read the specs carefully and see the notes on the 302 status as well.

It's much more useful to handle the payment over an API on server-side instead of risking a user being irritated by additional messages displayed by the browser where the user must actually decide whether or not the additional redirect is to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CURL extension](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php) to post request to payment server when processing your user's request on server-side.

If your user must be redirected to some external web site, than save needed data first and then redirect him using `header()` function. Keep in mind that in this case you wouldn't be able to use POST method for making request to remote payment server.

Answer (score 0):

A redirection with HTTP Location would have your user end on another site. I suggest you trigger an HTTP-request from your server using [curl](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [streams](http://de.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

Answer (score 0):

The reason they initially suggested AJAX is for user experience, and is not a requirement for a form to be able to post.  You will need to either present the user with a separate step to choose a form or  have the same page reload or load another page.

Some pseudocode for example:

```
<?php
   if (!isset($_POST['form_type']) { 
       display_form_selection();
   } else {
       switch ($_GET['form_type']) {
           case 'credit_card': display_form('credit_card');
                   exit;
           case 'cash': display_form('cash');
                   exit;
           default: display_form_selection(); 
                    die()
       }
   }
```

Your form_selection() routine should draw a form which has a select, checkbox, radio button or whatever that will POST a string or integer (for the switch) back to the script you are running from.

When the page reloads it will call the correct display_form() based on the value it passed to itself.  These functions will set up the form for whatever you want to post to the gateway.

I have read elsewhere on this site that using  for your form action is not a good idea, and you should rather manually type your script name in.